# How do I get an invitation to enter Kosovo?

Tags: invitation-letters, turkish-citizens, kosovo

As a Turkish citizen, I have the right to stay in Kosovo 90 days without a visa. But how do  I enter the Kosovo at first? What documents do I need besides passport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Kosovo grants Turkish citizens visa-free entry for short stays, it is a sign that they don't plan to subject most entering Turks to greater scrutiny than what can reasonably be done on the fly at the border checkpoint.

This has to mean that they don't *routinely* demand extensive paperwork such as letters of invitation -- if they did, there would be a visa requirement so they had a chance to get a good look at it in peace and quiet.

So unless you arouse *more* suspicion in the border guard than most other Turks do, what you will need is just your passport, and convincing answers to standard questions: What is the purpose of your trip? Where will you stay? When and how will you leave Kosovo again? Be prepared to document your accommodation bookings, tickets for the journey back home, and that you have enough money for your expenses during the trip.

(if you think you do look suspicious, arm yourself with as much documentation as you can lay your hand on, and hope for the best).

Comment: @CatwithaFez: You'll never be able to get a guarantee that such-and-such is sufficient documentation to be admitted; ultimately it will always be up to the whims and gut feeling of the border guard. What you need to do is be convincing, not to satisfy formal criteria. If you have concrete plans for only two days out of a month's stay, I _expect_ that you'll need a pretty good story explaining why you've done so little planning -- but I don't know how good is good enough.

Comment: A Turkish Citizen is granted visa free entry into Kosovo for up to 90 days. If you wish to stay longer, you will need to apply for a Stay and Work Permit at the Foreigner Registration Office.